# Bash replace line in a file with multiline file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file which has some place holder values:

Example:

```
Parent:
   Child: x
   Child2: <place-holder>

Car:
   Seat: x
   Door: <place-holder>
```

I am accomplishing this with `sed` in a way that works on both MacOS and Linux

```
sed -i .bak "s/<place-holder>/$REPLACEMNET_VALUE/g" file.yml
```

What I need to accomplish now is one step further, to inject a section in this file.

I have a file with several lines in the proper format and the location of that file in an environment variable.

```
sed -i .bak "s/<place-holder-section>/$(<$CONFIG_OPTIONS_TEMP)/g" config.yml
```

However, sed seems to not be able to handle multiple lines (without escaping).

Error:

```
sed: 1: "s/<place-holder-section>/ f ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

This could probably be solved with some looping and grepping for the line position and such but I am hoping maybe someone has a more elegant solution, possibly using awk? Keeping MacOS cross-compatibility is a concern as well.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed has another command 'r filename' "append text read from filename".  So if all the text to be inserted is in a file by itself, you could use this sed command.

Example:

```
bjb@blueeyes:~$ cat /tmp/old
Parent:
  Child: x
  Child2: <place-holder>

Car:
  Seat: x
  Door: <place-holder2>


<foo>


bjb@blueeyes:~$ cat /tmp/new
CarSeat:
    padding: fluff
    belt:  seat-belt-stuff

bjb@blueeyes:~$ sed '/<foo>/ {
> x
> r /tmp/new
> }' /tmp/old
Parent:
  Child: x
  Child2: <place-holder>

Car:
  Seat: x
  Door: <place-holder2>



CarSeat:
    padding: fluff
    belt:  seat-belt-stuff



bjb@blueeyes:~$
```

The sed command is addressed to the marker  in file /tmp/old - it puts that line in the hold space and never retrieves it so it has the effect of replacing the marker  with the contents of the file /tmp/new.

Comment: Yes, `r`.  Why `x` and not `d`?

Comment: @stevesliva see my answer as to why `d` can not proceed the `r` command. Also note that the `x` command will introduce an additional newline into the final file before the inserted file.

Comment: @brenda Thank you! I am sure this is the correct answer. I wonder if maybe you can help me with one last thing that seems to be throwing me. I am attempting to use this in a bash script and it appears to work however as your example shows, the new file is piped to stdout. after "/tmp/old" I added " > /tmp/old" which I would have assumed would overwrite the old file with the new information but for some reason, this produces a blank file with no output (no output was expected).

Would you happen to have any insight as to why that cant seem to be redirected?

Comment: ^ Solution. Use "| tee filename"

Comment: @Kyle.Tryon, when you give a command like `sed 's/tu/ff/' /tmp/old > /tmp/old`, bash first clears out /tmp/old, then runs sed and reads from the (newly emptied) /tmp/old - that's why it didn't work.  If you want to edit /tmp/old in-place, you can use another sed option"-i":  `sed -i 's/tu/ff' /tmp/old`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/<foo>/{r insertFile' -e 'd}' file
```

On encountering a line containing `<foo>` replace it by the contents of `insertFile`.

N.B. The solution consists of two parts: the `r insertFile` needs to normally end in a newline but the `-e` option can emulate this, thus the second part is likewise introduced with another `-e` option that deletes the found line. The `d` must also be the last command as any other commands following it, will never by executed.